# sysctl kernel core pattern not working with ~

Tags: debian, dump, sysctl

I'm trying to put core dumps in home directory but for whatever reason a core pattern starting with `~` does not work while using full path works just fine. Can't seem to find this rule in [docs](https://linux.die.net/man/5/core).

Not working, no core dumps generated:

`sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=~/.coredump/%E.%t.core`

Working, core dumps generated:

`sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/home/$USER/.coredump/%E.%t.core`

How come the lines works differently? Is it just my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first command the substitution of the `~` isn't done. If you will check later the value of this sysctl variable, you'll see that. The path should be absolute.

The `~` is a shell feature. And not every shell implements it. Better use the `$HOME` environment variable [defined by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html).

Comment: That is my conclusion too - no substitution performed. However there is no mention of this behavior in any docs I know of that `~` shouldn't be substituted, which makes me wonder if it's a bug or (more likely) by-design according to docs I don't know about. To me `~` is as fundamental as it gets, and I would assume it's substituted on creating the core dump file.

Comment: To get yourself familiar with fundamental things, you're talking about, you need to study them. `~` is _SHELL_'s notation.

Comment: @Andreas It's not a bug. And `~` is not really fundamental. It's a shell feature, and only in some shells, not a fundamental feature of the OS.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks, didn't realize "it's a shell feature".